# Button automatic cancel the ride

Tags: java, android, firebase, driver, uber-api

i have one button they call

mRequest request >>  wen i pressed the button they call a driver, but if dont have a driver i want to put a timer for auto cancel the ride request, only pressing the button again automatically

```
        mRequest.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (requestBol){
                    endRide();


                }else {
                    int selectId = mRadioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();

                    final RadioButton radioButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(selectId);

                    if (radioButton.getText() == null) {
                        return;
                    }

                    requestService = radioButton.getText().toString();
                    requestBol = true;

                    String userId = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();

                    DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("customerRequest");
                    GeoFire geoFire = new GeoFire(ref);
                    geoFire.setLocation(userId, new GeoLocation(mLastLocation.getLatitude(), mLastLocation.getLongitude()));

                    pickupLocation = new LatLng(mLastLocation.getLatitude(), mLastLocation.getLongitude());
                    pickupMarker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(pickupLocation).title("Aguarde aqui!").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.mipmap.ic_pickup)));

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Aguarde que estamos localizando o moto táxi mais próximo!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    mRequest.setText("Localizando seu moto táxi....");

                    getClosestDriver();
                }

            }
        });
```